# Preselecting Email Option from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, email

Currently when a user clicks the email button it shows all their emails that are registered on their iPhone. They requested that **only their work email gets chosen** automatically. The preferred email has its own domain (ex. @scooby.com)

As per my information, this is device configuration that is not possible from a webpage. However, any help or direction into the possibility of doing this is quite appreciated.

Comment: please share the html

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "the email button".

Comment: "<a href="mailto:person1@scooby.com?cc=person2@scooby.com">"